# Producer Consumer with one producer and multiple consumers

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I am implementing producer-consumer where items to be consumed are of 1000 types type-0, type-1, ..., type-999.

Producer inserts item of type-i in queue. Consumer uses that to update state machine for type-i(one state machine per type-i) based on item(type-i)removed from queue.There are multiple consumers that are reading from same queue (and one producer)

Condition is *if some consumer is processing item of type-i then other consumers cannot process item of same type so if other consumers pick up next items of same type type-i, all consumers get blocked which is not good solution.*

Another solution is to have 1000 queues and 1000 consumers for each type-i which is not feasible

Another solution is to have 10 queues and 10 consumers(one for each queue) and assign 100 types to Q-1, 100 types to Q2 etc. But problem is if consumer-j takes lots of time to process item-i all other items in queue will face delay though other consumer-k might be idle.

Whats good design pattern we can use here ?

**UPDATE:**

1. Solution-1 : (1 Queue - 1 Consumer) per type : Best solution but lot of threads
2. Solution-2: (1 Queue - m Consumers) per n Types : Problem is we might reach state where all consumers are waiting on processing type-i as first consumer still working on type-i item holding lock(type-i)

**UPDATE 2:**

Here ordering of items is IMP and cannot be altered. You can assume one state machine per type-i and consumer modifies state as per new item(of type-i) received. Now u can see why item ordering is important

Comment: Is it a FixedThreadPool? I.e. will there be a fixed predefined number of consumer threads? Or is this still open for design?

Comment: Its design and hence open. I have added update

Comment: It's an interesting question but I wonder if it is a good fit for SO?

Comment: Can you send message to the end to the original queue if execution of this task is blocked? In other words, is the order of processing important?

Comment: Yes SimY4...Thanks updated question, Ordering is imp

Comment: I think this question rather belongs to [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @RomanVottner when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: [cross-post on programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/326401/producer-and-multiple-consumers-with-limited-types-item)

Answer (score 1):

If we dive deeper into problem, we can see that each item type is processed in a parallel-fashion: there is no resource contention, no cooperation beetween processes, except for the fact that all those items are hold into the same buffer. So this does not sound like the best design choice.

If you need FIFO order when process your items you could put them into queue and, on the other "side", a single so called "dispatcher" thread" take them from the queue. Then, a single thread* for each item type comes with it's own queue, loaded from the dispatcher thread. So you have 1000+1 producer/consumer problems

*Yes, 1000 thread are not few....so you can decide to start 1000/k threads where a thread processes a range ok k types

If you need load balancing, you could use different ranges for each thread, counting its queue average size. More sophisticated, maybe too many

Answer (score 0):

Read about the limitations of "queues and workers paradigm" in the rationale for Apache Storm here - [queues & workers paradigm - storm rationale](http://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Rationale.html). Your **requirement** is basically for **scalable real-time processing**, which can be addressed by using Apache Storm or Apache Spark. Read more [here](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2854894/application-development/spark-and-storm-for-real-time-computation.html).